# How to handle error when '<%# Bind("value") %> doesn't exist in binding?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have an issue with binding values to grid view.

```
<Columns>
  <asp:TemplateField Visible="false">
    <ItemTemplate>
      <asp:Label ID="customer_lbl" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("binded_employer") %>' Font-Size="10px" Visible="false">
    </asp:Label>                           
    </ItemTemplate>
  </asp:TemplateField>
...
```

I bind my values using DataTable binding:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();

con.Open();
sqlArchiveData.Fill(dt);
con.Close(); 
GridViewRaport.DataSource = dt;
GridViewRaport.DataBind();
```

But sometimes I don't want to bind `binded_employer`, but then I receive the error:

> DataBinding: 'System.Data.DataRowView' does not contain a property with the name 'binded_employer'.

Is there any way how can I skip this?

Comment: Your data source needs to include all the fields referenced by the gridview. There's no way to skip it AFAIK. But it looks like you already decided to make the field invisible, so what's really the problem? Isn't that enough?

Comment: no because my query have GROUP BY columns and I can't put that specific column into sql query

Comment: But you can add that column in DataTable if its not present in DataTable form select query.

Comment: "my query have GROUP BY columns and I can't put that specific column into sql query" In that case it sounds like your gridview doesn't suit your query and you need another one. Are you trying to bind the same gridview to multiple different queries with different columns? it's not clear. But it sounds like a bad idea.

Comment: @KevinShah good idea. Works